# Como implementar paginação em yesod?

Tags: haskell

Eu tenho um problema. Eu preciso que este código abaixo retorne uma quantidade específica de linhas (LimitTo), a partir de um número específico de resultados (OffsetBy). O código da aplicação que estou fazendo com este intuito é este:

```
getBuscR :: Int -> Handler Value
getBuscR pageNumber = do
   let numberOfPages = 15
   results <- runDB $ selectList [] [LimitTo numberOfPages, OffsetBy $ (pageNumber - 1) * numberOfpages]
   sendStatusJSON ok200 (object ["answer" := results])
```

Eu fiz o código anterior com base nesse exemplo que está na documentação do yesod. Mas acredito que esteja desatualizado: (o livro não é atualizado desde 2011!). O exemplo do livro é este:

```
resultsForPage pageNumber = do
    let resultsPerPage = 10
    selectList
        [ PersonAge >=. 18
        ]
        [ Desc PersonAge
        , Asc PersonLastName
        , Asc PersonFirstName
        , LimitTo resultsPerPage
        , OffsetBy $ (pageNumber - 1) * resultsPerPage
        ]
```

Comment: Jovem, nosso idioma é o portugues, traduza sua pergunta ai.

Comment: Qual versão do haskell/yesod ta usando ? se estiver na 2.0 isso está errado, ps, diga qual pra saber a resposta kk

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, obrigado!! Faltou o desc/asc (atributoDaTabela) para referenciar qual tabela está sendo tratada.